# How do I know which versions of pickle a particular version of Python supports?

Tags: python, pickle

I have a script that requires Python 2.6. I will be adding a large-ish pickled database to the next version, and I want to use the fastest version of pickling. How can I tell which versions of pickling are available in *every* version of Python 2.6 and later?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like so:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.compatible_formats
['1.0', '1.1', '1.2', '1.3', '2.0']
```

**Edit**

I think it's safe to rely on the latest documentation. For example the [pickle documentation for Python 3.2.1](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.1/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) states:

> There are currently 4 different protocols which can be used for
>   pickling.
>
> - Protocol version 0 is the original human-readable protocol and is    backwards compatible with earlier versions of Python.
> - Protocol version 1 is the old binary format which is also compatible    with earlier versions of Python.
> - Protocol version 2 was introduced in Python 2.3. It provides much    more efficient pickling of new-style classes.
> - Protocol version 3 was added in Python 3.0. It has explicit support    for bytes and cannot be unpickled by Python 2.x pickle modules. This
>     is the current recommended protocol, use it whenever it is possible.

I think that makes it easy to confirm!

To explicitly answer your question, this means Python 2.6-2.7 support Pickle versions <= 2.0, and Python 3.0-3.2 support Pickle versions <= 3.0.

Comment: That tells me the versions of pickle in my current runtime. I want to know the version of pickle available to *anyone* running *any* version of 2.6 or later.

Comment: There are now 5 protocols, with version 4 added in Python 3.4. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format