# Do pickle files change across versions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

Do pickle files change across versions? So if I create a pickle file, and send it to someone with a different version of pickle (still python 3), would they be able to read it? I want to generate pickles and share them to save people time. Of course there are modules and stuff. I can't read a picke file of a numpy array without numpy, but if I had numpy, would it work fine?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format

Comment: Related: [How do I know which versions of pickle a particular version of Python supports?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6687262/4518341)