# macOS 10.15.7 I was able to load a file using Python 2 cPickle but can't load it using Python 3.7 pickle

Tags: python, pickle, python-3.7, python-2.x

I was able to run this in Python 2

```
    with gzip.GzipFile(FILE_PATH, 'rb') as file:
        IKEA_training_images = cPickle.load(file)
```

But in my Python 3.7.4 environment I get the following error. How do I open this pickle file in Python 3.7.4?

```
    with gzip.GzipFile(FILE_PATH, 'rb') as file:
        IKEA_training_images = pickle.load(file)
```

```
IKEA_training_images = pickle.load(file)
```

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I know which versions of pickle a particular version of Python supports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687262/how-do-i-know-which-versions-of-pickle-a-particular-version-of-python-supports)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687262/how-do-i-know-which-versions-of-pickle-a-particular-version-of-python-supports Pickle versions have compatibility issues....